# Second Order Op Amp RLC Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, passive-networks

Is there a way to make an op amp circuit using only RLC and op amps that would make V0 = V1-4V'1 -3V''1 -5V2 possible? Assuming that V1 and V2 are independent sources and considering that the prime indicates derivative with respect to time. I have tried to use 1 op amp and connect RLC in series with V1 source but then I would have to derive V0. I have tried other ways and tried to solve with two op amps but still couldn't figure out the design. Sorry for the bad English and apologies if the question seems trivial; I have just learned circuits.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to design from a transfer function or coefficients and make active inductors using Caps but this is not the best way to design a filter due to the math work..

Comment: SEJ, why don't you combine the +3 and -4 coefficients of the first derivative of \$V_1\$?

Comment: IMO You need to provide a worked example/ your best attempts so far, otherwise it is very hard to try to help you.. In electronics any time the question is "Is this possible.." the answer is usually "Yes, (almost) everything is possible with electronics.." the more interesting question is not if but how, but if you want people to provide an example of how to do this then you need to first show your circuit and what attempts you have made yourself so far.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a typo. I meant V0 = V1 -4V'1 -3V''1 -5V2.

Comment: I was wondering if this could be done using only 1 op amp. I can't seem to find help online which explains RLC and op amp which would result in a similar fashion as the V0 equation written on the original post.